# Arranging for Android service to start again after phone restarts

Tags: java, android, android-service

i need a service in my app that starts first time and runs forever, even if user restart his phone, my service starts automatically without running my app. i write this code but when user restart his phone, my service doesn't start again!!

```
public class notifService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

and in the main activity i start service like this:

```
// start service
Intent service = new Intent(MainActivity.this, notifService.class);
MainActivity.this.startService(service);
```

thanks for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` in BroadcastReceiver and start your service.

For example

```
public class YourDefinedBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, notifService.class);
    context.startService(service);
    }
}
```

Also, you must hold the permission:

- [`RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED)

Ref: [Automatically starting Services in Android after booting](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/12/11/automatically-starting-services-in-android-after-booting/) and [Android Start Service on Boot Automatically](http://techblogon.com/android-start-service-on-boot/)